# WPF Handle links inside FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, flowdocument

I'm building simple dictionary application using WPF.

I'm using MVVM pattern, databinding and FlowDocument to display words to user.

UI consists of 2 controls: ListBox and FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

Dictionary data comes from XML file, format of this string may look like this

```
<b>Word</b> - Some description. Another <i>description</i>. Reference <ref id="123">related word</ref>
```

The order of  HTML and reference elements is not defined.

I parse HTML string, make it into XAML, then from XAML I create FlowDocument object and bind it to Document property of FlowDocumentScrollViewer control.

The problem arises when I need to link ref. elements. (my requirement is when user clicks on reference link, referenced word is selected in ListBox control and shown in FlowDocumentScrollViewer)

My question is there a way to dynamically create "hyperlink"-style controls (with event or commands attached) that would take user to referenced word in dictionary.

Is it possible to solve this problem at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Hyperlink text element that has a Command property and a Click event.  It behaves pretty much like a button, but it is used inside the FlowDocuments.  You can use either method to achieve what you are after, but I tend to prefer Commands.  Especially if you are implementing this using the MVVM pattern as you have tagged...

Comment: Thanks got it to work.

Hyperlink + Command solved the problem.