# How can I get a FlowDocument Hyperlink to launch browser and go to URL in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, flowdocument

The following code in a WPF app **creates** a hyperlink that looks and **acts** like a hyperlink, but doesn't **do** anything when clicked.

**What do I have to change so that when I click it, it opens the default browser and goes to the specified URL?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/4fbnq2.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/4fbnq2.png)

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestLink238492.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainArea"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TestLink238492
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FlowDocumentScrollViewer fdsv = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer();

            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
            fdsv.Document = doc;
            fdsv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
            doc.PagePadding = new Thickness(0);
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

            Run run = new Run("this is flow document text and ");
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);

            Run run2 = new Run("this is a hyperlink");
            Hyperlink hlink = new Hyperlink(run2);
            hlink.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(hlink);

            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "this is textblock text";
            sp.Children.Add(tb);
            sp.Children.Add(fdsv);

            MainArea.Content = sp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also the later http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf  - these two question should perhaps be merged but I'm not sure if they are true duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer to this one, you have to add **RequestNavigate** and handle it yourself:

```
Run run2 = new Run("this is a hyperlink");
Hyperlink hlink = new Hyperlink(run2);
hlink.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
hlink.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(hlink_RequestNavigate);
paragraph.Inlines.Add(hlink);


void hlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: And what if I load document from RTF?

Answer (score 12):

Got the solutions for this Poma. The code section below should be added to your class where you need to do this. Or you can put it in a static class somewhere if you need to get to it from multiple files. I've tweaked it slightly for what I'm doing.

```
    #region Activate Hyperlinks in the Rich Text box
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465667/handle-all-hyperlinks-mouseenter-event-in-a-loaded-loose-flowdocument
    void SubscribeToAllHyperlinks(FlowDocument flowDocument)
    {
        var hyperlinks = GetVisuals(flowDocument).OfType<Hyperlink>();
        foreach (var link in hyperlinks)
            link.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(link_RequestNavigate);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisuals(DependencyObject root)
    {
        foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root).OfType<DependencyObject>())
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendants in GetVisuals(child))
                yield return descendants;
        }
    }

    void link_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288999/how-can-i-get-a-flowdocument-hyperlink-to-launch-browser-and-go-to-url-in-a-wpf
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    #endregion Activate Hyperlinks in the Rich Text box
```

You'll call it in your code like this:

```
        string xaml = HTMLConverter.HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(this.itemControl.NotificationItem.Body, true);
        FlowDocument flowDocument = XamlReader.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xaml))) as FlowDocument;
        SubscribeToAllHyperlinks(flowDocument);
        bodyFlowDocument.Document = flowDocument;
```

All the HTMLConverter stuff can be found at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx
That's if you need to convert HTML to a Flow Document. Although, that's slightly out of the scope of this topic.

Comment: At firts, this solution didn't work for me, all the hyperlinks were disabed. Only after I changed `SubscribeToAllHyperlinks` and used `link.Command` instead of an event handler, everything worked smoothly. I am using .Net 4.5, maybe this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not *quite* work for me. As detailed in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2566#issuecomment-590148940), `UseShellExecute = true` needs to be included. Thus, the `RequestNavigateEventHandler` will look like:

```
void hlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e) {
    var sInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    sInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sInfo);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```