# Handle all Hyperlinks MouseEnter event in a loaded loose Flowdocument

Tags: wpf, events, flowdocument, mouseenter

I'm new to WPF, working on my first project. I've been stuck in this problem for a week so I'm trying to find some help here.

I have a FlowDocumentReader inside my app, wich loads several FlowDocuments (independent files as loose xaml files).

I need to handle the MouseEnter event for all the Hyperlinks in the loaded document but I cannot set MouseEnter="myHandler" in XAML as theese are loose XAML files.

Is there any way to parse de FlowDocument and set the handlers when loading it?

Any other solution? Sorry for the Newbie question, thanks A LOT in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading your `FlowDocument` you can enumerate all UIElements using `LogicalTreeHelper`. It will allow you to find all hyperlinks. Then you can simply subscribe to their `MouseEnter` event. Here is a code:

```
    void SubscribeToAllHyperlinks(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hyperlinks = GetVisuals(this).OfType<Hyperlink>();
        foreach (var link in hyperlinks)
            link.MouseEnter += Hyperlink_MouseEnter;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisuals(DependencyObject root)
    {
        foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root).OfType<DependencyObject>())
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendants in GetVisuals(child))
                yield return descendants;
        }
    }

    private void Hyperlink_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
```

I've tested it with following XAML:

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Hyperlink>asf</Hyperlink>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://xtrememvvm.codeplex.com/

It lets you hook directly into events handlers from loose XAML files.

No docs, but the sample app demos using routed commands and event handlers.

- Clay