# How to catch Hyperlink click events in the container - loosly coupled way?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

For start - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465667/handle-all-hyperlinks-mouseenter-event-in-a-loaded-loose-flowdocument) is exactly what I want to achieve, but without the run-time overhead of walking each `Hyperlink`.

Is there a way to catch the `Click` event of `Hyperlink` in higher level (e.g. in `Window`) ?

`PreviewMouseDown` event gives me the `Run` element in which the `Hyperlink` located (via `e.Source` or `e.OriginalSource`), not the `Hyperlink` itself.

#### Edit - solution, thanks to @nit:

[Why Setter Property is not applied on Hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558424/why-setter-property-is-not-applied-on-hyperlink)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you can do in PreviewMouseDown event handler:

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

            Run r = e.OriginalSource as Run;

            if(r != null)
            {
                Hyperlink hyperlink = r.Parent as Hyperlink;

                if(hyperlink != null)
                {

                    //Your code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or if you want that all the hyperlink click should be redirected to same command handler in your ViewModel you can add style to do this as follows:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
    </Style>
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks! that works... a bit embarrassing that I didn't think of it myself... however I'm still interested in a more elegant solution, like command binding or something like that...

Comment: command bindings can not give you UI elements. Can you please tell what exactly you want to achieve by getting to the hyperlink level?

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but something like that - I have many `Hyperlink`s, and I want to catch them in one place (they all have the same functionality ). Since I serialize and deserialize them all the time, I have to reconnect their behavior after each deserialization.

Comment: the updated answer, if works (I assume it does...), seems like an ideal solution. I'll test it in few days and let know. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, didn't use `Command`s at the end, but your answer guided me to [the ideal solution for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558424/why-setter-property-is-not-applied-on-hyperlink)