# Why Setter Property is not applied on Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, eventsetter

I want to set (e.g.) `FontSize` for all `Hyperlink`s in my window. This is my `MainWindow`'s `XAML` content:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Hyperlink_OnClick"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                something
                <Hyperlink>
                    <Hyperlink.Inlines>
                    clickable
                    </Hyperlink.Inlines>
                </Hyperlink> ...
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

If I add the style explicitly it works... (i.e. add `x:Key="HyperlinkStyle"` to the `Style` tag, and add `Style="HyperlinkStyle"` to the `Hyperlink`)

How can I set the style automatically to all `Hyperlink`s ?

### Edit:

@keyboardP, @Anatoliy and @kmatyaszek - you're all right... Thanks to you all! I finally moved the `Style` tag to the `<RichTextBox.Resources>` property.

Comment: It might actually be by design according the the blog post linked in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182135/how-to-propagate-styles-to-hyperlinks-inside-a-datatemplate

Comment: Strangely, I do so only works in `RichTextBox`, in `TextBlock` for example, works fine. The events in `RichTextBox` earned, you need to add them to the `BlockUIContainer`.

Comment: You should set `OverridesDefaultStyle` to true `<RichTextBox OverridesDefaultStyle="True">` or you can move Hyperlink style from Window resources to RichTextBox resources. This should help.

Comment: @kmatyaszek - please post an answer so I could accept it (I think that your solution is both complete and concise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `OverridesDefaultStyle` to true:

```
<RichTextBox OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
```

or you can move `Hyperlink` style from `Window` resources to `RichTextBox` resources.