# Example using Hyperlink in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I've seen several suggestions, that you can add hyperlink to WPF application through `Hyperlink` control.

Here's how I'm trying to use it in my code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        x:Class="BookmarkWizV2.InfoPanels.Windows.UrlProperties"
        Title="UrlProperties" Height="754" Width="576">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <StackPanel >
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Url:" Margin="5" 
                            DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Width="Auto">
                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.co.in">
                                    Click here
                            </Hyperlink>   
                        </TextBox>                      
                    </DockPanel >
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>        
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,7,2,7" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Button Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Accept" Margin="15,3" />
            </Button>
            <Button Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Cancel" Margin="15,3" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm getting following error:

> Property 'Text' does not support values of type 'Hyperlink'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 381, accepted):

If you want your application to open the link in a [web browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser) you need to add a [HyperLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink) with the [RequestNavigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.requestnavigate) event set to a function that programmatically opens a web-browser with the address as a parameter.

```
<TextBlock>           
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        Click here
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

In the code-behind you would need to add something similar to this to handle the RequestNavigate event:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    // for .NET Core you need to add UseShellExecute = true
    // see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute#property-value
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

In addition you will also need the following imports:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
```

It will look like this in your application:

[image: oO]

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to specify the link-text ("Click here" in this case) through binding ?

Comment: Simply put a Textblock inside the Hyperlink again and Bind the Textproperty

Comment: Is it possible to make this execute a command instead of follow a link?

Comment: @Thomas - To execute a command, simply bind the necessary command to the Hyperlink's Command property.

Comment: **Important remark**: you must have a non empty NavigateUri or event RequestNavigate is never called

Comment: I had to do it that way: Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) { UseShellExecute = true });   otherwise it was saying it was not finding the specified file.

Comment: I use the Click Event rather than the RequestNavigate for the Hyperlink and working properly. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 73):

In addition to Fuji's response, we can make the handler reusable turning it into an attached property:

```
public static class HyperlinkExtensions
{
    public static bool GetIsExternal(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsExternalProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsExternal(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsExternalProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExternalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsExternal", typeof(bool), typeof(HyperlinkExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsExternalChanged));

    private static void OnIsExternalChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var hyperlink = sender as Hyperlink;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
        else
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate -= Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
    }

    private static void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://stackoverflow.com"
               custom:HyperlinkExtensions.IsExternal="true">
        Click here
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thank you

Answer (score 33):

If you want to localize string later, then those answers aren't enough, I would suggest something like:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://speechcentral.net/">
       <Hyperlink.Inlines>
            <Run Text="Click here"/>
       </Hyperlink.Inlines>
   </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 32):

`Hyperlink` is *not* a control, it is a [flow content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753113%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element, you can only use it in controls which support flow content, like a `TextBlock`. `TextBoxes` only have plain text.

Answer (score 27):

Note too that `Hyperlink` does not have to be used for navigation. You can connect it to a command.

For example:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ClearCommand}">Clear</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 26):

I used the marked answer in this question and I had an issue with it.

It returns an exception: `{"The system cannot find the file specified."}`

After a bit of investigation. It turns out that if your WPF application is a .NET Core application, you need to change `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

This is mentioned in Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8#property-value):

> true if the shell should be used when starting the process; false if
> the process should be created directly from the executable file. The
> default is true on .NET Framework apps and false on .NET Core apps.

So to make this work you need to add `UseShellExecute` and set it to `true`:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri){ UseShellExecute = true });
```

Comment: I had this same issue and came here to see how to fix it, but it still persists with `UseShelExecute = true` any idea why?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter so just to understand you made UseShelExecute = true but still have the same issue? if that is the case try to run your visual studio in admin mode (run as administrator) I think this process need to access resources that required admin privilege. And this true thing is only valid for .core projects. let me know if that helps so I can update my answer.

Comment: yes, I am running as my admin user and have `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) { UseShellExecute = true });` and get the error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'" when I try to follow the hyperlink

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter not sure else what it can be, if you have source code I am welling to spend some time debugging it but wont promise any thing. :)

Comment: Not really shareable code sadly - I have just had to not use a hyperlink for now rather than hold the project up. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter no problem any other time ;)

Answer (score 25):

IMHO the simplest way is to use new class inherited from `Hyperlink`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Opens <see cref="Hyperlink.NavigateUri"/> in a default system browser
/// </summary>
public class ExternalBrowserHyperlink : Hyperlink
{
    public ExternalBrowserHyperlink()
    {
        RequestNavigate += OnRequestNavigate;
    }

    private void OnRequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I liked Arthur's idea of a reusable handler, but I think there's a simpler way to do it:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType() != typeof (Hyperlink))
        return;
    string link = ((Hyperlink) sender).NavigateUri.ToString();
    Process.Start(link);
}
```

Obviously there could be security risks with starting any kind of process, so be carefull.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most beautiful ways in my opinion (since it is now commonly available) is using behaviours.

It requires:

- nuget dependency: `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`
- if you already have behaviours built in you might have to follow this [guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/10/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/) on Microsofts blog.

xaml code:

```
xmlns:Interactions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

AND

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Link}">
    <Interactions:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:HyperlinkOpenBehaviour ConfirmNavigation="True"/>
    </Interactions:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Hyperlink.Inlines>
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Link}"/>
    </Hyperlink.Inlines>
</Hyperlink>
```

behaviour code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class HyperlinkOpenBehaviour : Behavior<Hyperlink>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ConfirmNavigationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ConfirmNavigation), typeof(bool), typeof(HyperlinkOpenBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool ConfirmNavigation
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(ConfirmNavigationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ConfirmNavigationProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.RequestNavigate += NavigationRequested;
            this.AssociatedObject.Unloaded += AssociatedObjectOnUnloaded;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        private void AssociatedObjectOnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= AssociatedObjectOnUnloaded;
            this.AssociatedObject.RequestNavigate -= NavigationRequested;
        }

        private void NavigationRequested(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!ConfirmNavigation || MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Question", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                OpenUrl();
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void OpenUrl()
        {
//          Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(AssociatedObject.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri));
            MessageBox.Show($"Opening {AssociatedObject.NavigateUri}");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.RequestNavigate -= NavigationRequested;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help someone as well.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace Helpers.Controls
{
    public class HyperlinkEx : Hyperlink
    {
        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            base.OnClick();

            Process p = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = this.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri
                }
            };
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XMAL binding example is as flowing:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Hyperlink Command="local:MyCommands.ViewDetails" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
  </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```