# How to display a website only in the default browser

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently having an issue after a click on an hyperlink inside a wpf Page.In my `RequestNavigate` or `Click` (both have the same behavior in this situation) event I do the usual `Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateURI)`.The problem is that this event opens the webpage both in the default browser (the behavior I'm looking for) and in my wpf Page object as well which I don't want.I was wondering if there was any workaround for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default web browser will open whatever page you pass into `Process.Start`

Comment: The thing is the website is displayed in my wpf Page as well.

Comment: Are you using a hyperlink with a Url, or just a label or a button?

Comment: Hyperlink with an url, I guess there is a default behavior for hyperlink inside a wpf page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your current page also loads with the Url is because you are using a `Hyperlink`. Try using either a `Hyperlink` with no Url, a button or a styled `Label`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `e.Handled = true` to say you have already handled the hyperlink

See [Example using Hyperlink in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf)