# link email address and send email via outlook

Tags: wpf, email, hyperlink

I am working on a wpf app, and I have a Customer Information section where I can record my customer information. In this section, I use a textbox recording customer's email address. But now I want to make the email address hyperlink and link the email address via Outlook email, say, if I click the email address, it opens the outlook email automatically so that I can send email via outlook. Appreciate for samples. Thanks.

what I want is a Label or Textblock whose text is Email on the left (do not need to bind to the text in the textbox), a Textbox on the right where you can type an email address. After you type a valid email address in the textbox, you can click the email address, and it will open outlook automatically. In the To of outlook, the email address is what you typed in.

```
<TextBlock Text="Email" Grid.Row="11" x:Name="lblEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 

<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" x:Name="txtEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextDecorations="UnderLine" Foreground="Blue"
        Text="{Binding Email,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Please see answer provided by Sheridan from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378707/hyperlink-email-address-in-textbox-and-send-it-via-outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to send my e-mails... note that this is not specifically for Outlook... it will use whichever software is the default e-mail program that is set on the user's computer:

```
public bool SendEmail(List<string> toAddresses, List<string> ccAddresses, string fromAddress, string emailSubject, string emailBody, bool isBodyHtml)
{
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
    email.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
    foreach (string address in toAddresses) email.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
    foreach (string address in ccAddresses) email.CC.Add(new MailAddress(address));
    email.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    email.IsBodyHtml = false;
    email.Subject = emailSubject;
    email.Body = emailBody;
    email.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(Settings.Default.DefaultEmailServerPath);
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Default.EmailNetworkCredentialUserName, Settings.Default.EmailNetworkCredentialPassword, Settings.Default.EmailNetworkCredentialDomain);
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpClient.Host = Settings.Default.DefaultEmailServerPath;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    try { smtpClient.Send(email); }
    catch { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Note that I have overloaded methods for this, so this one has all the options in it... you can freely remove several lines if you prefer. There is also a shortcut way of sending an e-mail:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:youremail@yourcompany.com");
```

Basically, I would add either a `HyperLink` control, or a `Button` that has a `Command` into your UI and then call this code from your handler. You can find out more about the `HyperLink` control from the [Hyperlink class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.hyperlink.aspx) page at MSDN and there is a good example found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf).

UPDATE >>>

You really should provide code examples... I have no idea how you have set up your `TextBox`, whether you are binding or not, the names of the parameters and so forth. As such, I can only make assumptions that you will have to relate to your own code.

First, add a `Hyperlink` control in the *same* place as your `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="EmailTextBox" Text="{Binding Email}" 
    Visibility="{Binding IsValidEmail, Converter={StaticResource 
    InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=EmailTextBox}" Visibility="{
    Binding IsValidEmail, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

You see the basic idea here is to have the two controls share one UI location and 'take turns' to be visible depending on the value of the `TextBox`. Therefore, you'll need to add a `bool` property (`IsValidEmail` in my example) that you set to true when the text value is a valid e-mail address. Then the `BoolToVisibilityConverter` will convert that true value to `Visibility.Visible` for the `Hyperlink` control and the `InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter` will convert that false value to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Hidden` for the `Hyperlink` control. I hope and trust that you can work the rest out yourself as my time is limited today.

Comment: Hi, Sharidan. Thanks for your quick reploy. I have already read the post and got similar sample about sending email using wpf. But it is not what I want. Now I want make the email address hypelink and after I type the email address and press it, the outlook email page will display automatically so that email can be sent.

Comment: @DanielXu, the last link that I provided you with will take you to a post on StackOverflow where a `Hyperlink` is created and used... just what you want.

Comment: What I want is after typing an email, the email address is hyperlink. Then, I press the email address and it opens outlook. The post enables me to write a text hypelink and the email address is fixed, say "Click Me", after u press "Click Me", outlook is open and the receipt is what you set up first (fixed).

Comment: If I understand you correctly from your latest comment, then you want to add a hyperlink containing the text that a user has just entered into a `TextBox`... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want. Sorry for not clarify. I did so much research, but I did not find. Do you have such sample? thanks

Comment: I tried your code, but it has error say **The property 'Text' was not found in type 'Hyperlink'**. I post my code now. Please see the update question. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... the text comes from the content... the `TextBlock` whose `Text` property is bound to the value of the `TextBox`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: <TextBox Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" Name="EmailTextBox" Text="{Binding Email,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
    Visibility="{Binding IsValidEmail, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Hyperlink Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=EmailTextBox}" Visibility="{Binding 
        IsValidEmail, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
   </Hyperlink>

Comment: I use the above code, error message says **A value of type 'Hyperlink' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'**

Comment: Sorry once more... I can't test this code at the moment. The problem was that you must add `Hyperlink` objects inside something like a `TextBlock` control. I have updated my answer code again.

Comment: @ Sheridan. I also did research, we can only use Hypelink inside Textblock. But when I use your update code, there is no build errors, but the app crashes and throw error 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'

Comment: My code: <TextBox Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" Name="EmailTextBox" Text="{BindingEmail,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
Visibility="{Binding IsValidEmail, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0">
    <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=EmailTextBox}" Visibility="{Binding IsValidEmail, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" /></Hyperlink></TextBlock>

Comment: Dude, you have to add two `BoolToVisibility` converters into your `Resources` section... call one `BoolToVisibilityConverter` and the other `InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter`... come on... you have to do *some* of this yourself.

Comment: Sorry, your code still does not work. I did try a lot before asking the question. At first I use this code, it can open outlook, but the email address in **To** field is not what I typed. It is what I defined in Hyperlink_RequestNavigate behind: <TextBlock Text="Email" Grid.Row="11" x:Name="lblEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:info@kramerel.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" /> </Hyperlink> </TextBlock>

Comment: private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e) {System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=hello&body=love my body";proc.Start(); e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: Basically, what I want is a Label or Textblock whose text is **Email** on the left (do not need to bind to the text in the textbox), a Textbox on the right where you can type an email address. After you type a valid email address in the textbox, you can click the email address, and it will open outlook automatically. In the **To** of outlook, the email address is what you typed in. I may not clarify in my question. I do understand your code and tried to fix errors while replying to you, not just wait for your answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Try updating the `TextBox` binding with this: `Text="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`.

Comment: I have tried that before, it does not work, either. My current problem is how to write the code in private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)  to get the email address in the **To** field of the outlook.

Comment: I found a sample yesterday http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9151/LinkTextBox-a-quick-solution-for-entering-emails-a , but it is for windowsform. The email address function is what i want in the sample. But I tried but  i still have no idea how to implement that in wpf

Comment: Buddy, this has gone on too long... start a fresh question with a link to this one.

Comment: @Shredian. Thanks so much for your help, haha... I will create a new question linking to this one.

Comment: Where does Settings.Default.DefaultEmailServerPath come from? I can't find that anywhere. Thanks

Comment: `Settings.Default` is the default name for the application/user settings files. See [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings) on MSDN for more information on settings. `DefaultEmailServerPath` is just the name of a custom setting, in which the default e-mail server path is stored, so you won't have one... until you add one. ;)