# Runtime Error: WPF IOException Cannot locate resource

Tags: wpf, runtime-error

Refering to my previous question **hyperlink email address in textbox and send it via Outlook** from
[hyperlink email address in textbox and send it via Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378707/hyperlink-email-address-in-textbox-and-send-it-via-outlook), my desired function has been achieved by the suggested answer. But I met a runtime error, [image]

I have tried solutions from the link [WPF IOException Cannot locate resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518603/wpf-ioexception-cannot-locate-resource) and http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2007/08/05/wpf-gotcha-cannot-locate-resource-filename-xaml.aspx. I still did not fix the problem. I think the problem is my **Email** textbox is in the **View/Organisationv/OrganisationSview.xmal** , but when the app runs it locates **View/Organisationv**. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.
 [image]

Comment: @Sheridan. Hi Sheridan. I have tried a lot to fix this run time problem (including Clean Solution-- Rebuild, change the assembly name to make it different from the namespace...) but I don't find the solution. I also tried to implement the email hyperlink in other folders, it works fine. The most likely problem I think is that I renamed the foler **OrganisationView** to **OrganisationV**, I cannot remeber. Are you professional in this area? Any suggestions?