# I have a string that has a reference to a document (example c:\users\testdocument.doc)

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I just want to open it by clicking on a button or a hyperlink. It dont want to open it inside my program

Comment: Hi Chris. Take a look at the SO help topic [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example using Hyperlink in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf?rq=1). Refer to the accepted answer.

Comment: i will do this, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to open it within your application that means you will open it using the office application. 
since you dont mention which programming language you use (i am guessing, from the wpf tag, some Visual Studio language) as the `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcyt0y1f.aspx` states

for c#

```
this.Application.Documents.Open(@"c:\users\testdocument.doc");
```

and for VB

```
Me.Application.Documents.Open("c:\users\testdocument.doc")
```

And opening it as read only

C#

```
this.Application.Documents.Open(@"c:\users\testdocument.doc", ReadOnly:true);
```

VB

```
Me.Application.Documents.Open(FileName:="c:\users\testdocument.doc", ReadOnly:=True)
```